# First span (onclick) of html page not working

Tags: html, pug, simplemodal

I have an Html page with cards this is my jade code:

```
          div(id="myModal" + i class="modal")
            div(class="modal-content")
              span(class="close" onclick="closeMoviePopup(#{i})") &times;
              h2= movie.name
              a(href="sodaplayer:?url=" + movie.magnet_link + "&title=" + movie.name onclick="(function(){ document.getElementById('myModal#{i}').style.display = 'none'; })();return true;") Stream
```

js:

```
function closeMoviePopup(index) {
    document.getElementById('myModal' + index).style.display = 'none';
}
```

For some reason, every card works except the first one I don't understand why that would happen. It is not a problem with the i variable or the function I don't get what it is

Comment: Are you sure its not off-by-one error. If not could you share the rendered html?

Comment: I dont think so, how can I check?

Comment: Check the id of the first card

Comment: In an array of 35 length it returned 0 for the first index and 34 for the last index, so is that the problem?

Comment: Could you possibly share a screenshot of how this card appears when you inspect it in the dev tools?

Comment: Also if you wanna check the html yourself: www.venomstream.com/app and click on the first all the way to the left

Comment: screenshot: https://imgur.com/nnDUq4V

Comment: I'm checking the app. Seems everything is fine but still isn't working. It works if I'm editing on the dev tool though.

Comment: weird would you know any way to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in you index.js you are capturing the first span `var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];` and executing a different function. Fix
that and it should work.